# How to get current umbraco user details using js

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, umbraco

I want to get umbraco current user details (not a member, only user/admin). I need to get my details using JS,I use userService, it returns undefined.. and I don't know why...
Is there a way to get current user details using ng & js??

//js - example

```
angular.module('umbraco').controller('LoginController', [

    '$scope',
    '$http',
    'editorState',
    'contentResource',
    'userService',

    function ($scope, $http, editorState, contentResource, userService) {

        $scope.loginAsMember = function () {                                            
            var _memberId = editorState.current.id;
            $scope.curUser =  userService.getCurrentUser();                     
            );
        };     
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at '/Umbraco/Js/umbraco.contollers.js' right around line 2170, you can see how `userService.getCurrentUser()` is being used.

`userService.getCurrentUser()` returns a promise object, so you can use `.then()` in order to set your `$scope.user`, then do what you need to do.

So try something like...

```
angular.module('umbraco').controller('LoginController', [

   '$scope',
   '$http',
   'editorState',
   'contentResource',
   'userService',

   function ($scope, $http, editorState, contentResource, userService) {

       $scope.loginAsMember = function () {
              userService.getCurrentUser().then(function (user) {
                   var _memberId = editorState.current.id;
                   $scope.curUser = user;
                   console.log($scope.curUser.name);
              });
       };
   }
]);
```

Of course if in your view if you used `{{curUser.name }}`, then the two way data binding should handle it as soon as the user object is available. But if you want to use it in your JS, then you'll need special care to make sure the object exists before using it through callbacks and promises, etc.